# Entities within Entities in Core Data - Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am using Core Data to store information in an iPhone application I am building.

I intend to store vocabulary objects within deck objects, so any deck object can have multiple vocabulary objects.

I thought of creating a property "Deck ID" in my vocabulary entity, and associate vocabulary cards with decks by IDs. However, I don't know if this is bad practice or not?

Is there a better way to do this with Core Data relationships? As far as I know a relationship means the Deck Entity will only have one Vocabulary object, maybe I am wrong about this.

How can I go about effectively building a core-data structure that will suit my needs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it. You can't "embed" an entity inside an entity.

If you want to have a `deck` entity that can have multiple instances of a `vocabulary` entity attached to it, you need to create **separate entities** for `deck` and `vocabulary`, and add a **to-many** relationship from your `deck` entity to your `vocabulary` entity, and a **to-one** relationship from your `vocabulary` entity back to your deck entity.

Here's a basic pair of entities in a Core Data model to demonstrate this:

[image: Relationship]

As you can see in the image, the `Deck` entity has a to-many relationship named `vocabularies` to the `Vocabulary` entity, with an inverse relationship `deck`.

The `vocabularies` relationship in the `Deck` entity is configured like so:

[image: Relationship Configuration 1]

and the `deck` relationship in the `Vocabulary` entity is configured like this:

[image: Relationship Configuration 2]

Note that the `vocabularies` relationship is **to-many**, while the `deck` relationship is not. This means that **there can be multiple vocabularies for one `Deck` object**, but **each `Vocabulary` object can only be connected to *one* `Deck` object**. This type of relationship is commonly represented as

```
Deck <---->> Vocabulary
```

which makes sense as you can see this is the same as the arrows in the image above connecting the two entities, denoting the type of relationship.

Core Data is at a higher level than interacting directly with a database (which it does for you), so you really don't need to think about it as a database. It's easier to think of Core Data as an ***object graph*** rather than a database, as this is what it represents: **a collection of objects, connected to each other**, not a set of disjoint tables that must be connected manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. If I create classes for both Deck and Vocabulary, how can I instantiate or add Vocabulary entities to a specific Deck? Is there a method I can use to do this?

Comment: @Yoni201 When you create a class for `Deck`, you will notice that it has an `NSSet` property called `vocabularies`, as well as a `CoreDataGeneratedAccessors` category on the object with methods you can use to add and remove objects from this set, all made for you. You won't need to implement anything yourself.

Comment: How would I fetch all of the vocabulary objects tied to a deck? I am successfully fetching decks, but I can't figure out how to fetch the vocabulary objects within the decks.

Comment: Just access the `vocabularies` property of your `Deck` object. It's an `NSSet` that contains all of the vocabulary objects associated with it.

Comment: So I don't need an NSFetchRequest for the vocabulary objects themselves? Just the Deck? Fetching the Deck fetches the vocabulary objects as well then...

Comment: No. Fetching the `Deck` objects will fetch all of the objects that they have references to.

Comment: I'm trying to access the vocabulary objects like so: [[Deck vocabularies] allObjects], but I am getting an error from this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Group 0x8c6c> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Terms.' What method should I use to access the objects that won't error out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31924/discussion-between-partiallyfinite-and-yoni201)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the learning curve with Core Data is to stop thinking about it as if it was a relational database.

It's best to think of it as an object graph - the way objects are linked together, rather than is a table joined by identifiers.

In your case, what you should do is to have a deck object and a vocabulary object and set up relationships like so:

```
deck <-->> vocabulary
```

(You'll see this notation a lot when people talk about Core Data)

This means that a deck object has a one-to-many relationship with vocabulary objects and vocabulary objects have a one-to-one relationship with deck objects. Having the relationship going both ways in important in CD.

If you do it this way, there is no need to manually create the ids and a table that joins the objects, it will be managed internally for you. All you need to to is to add and remove objects from the relationships. For Vocabulary objects this will just be a single object of deck's type, and for the deck it will be a Set of objects of vocabulary's type. Having the relationship going both ways means that if you, for example, create a vocabulary object and assign it to a deck, then the deck object will automatically have this vocabulary object added to its set of vocabulary objects.